# how to get the list name passed as a parameter to a function in python

Tags: python, list, parameters, arguments, inspect

I have function below, i just want to return "list_" from this, couldn't achieve though. any help would be appreciated.

```
import inspect

def f(*x, **y):
    _,_,_,lo=inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
    print(list(lo.values()))        

list_=[1,2,3,4]
f(list_)
```

Comment: Python argument passing passes objects, not names. `f` receives no information about the "list_" name. There's no requirement for a function's arguments to even *have* names. The closest you can get to what you're asking for is source code inspection, which is extremely fragile and breaks in like 5 different ways off the top of my head (calls from pyc-only modules, calls from C, multiple calls on the same line, calls from interactive mode, and calls by an unexpected function name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over your global variables stored in [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and return name of variable whose value is equal to argument supplied as `x[0]`. Here we use `next()` to stop iterating over `globals()` and return our value as soon as we find our match.

```
def f(*x, **y):
    return next(i for i in globals() if globals()[i] == x[0])

list_ = [1,2,3,4]
print(f(list_)) # -> "list_"
```

---

Or using `inspect`

```
def f(*x, **y):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    return next(var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is x[0])

print(f(list_)) # -> "list_"
```

Comment: thanks my friend, i've been humming for this since this morning, you made my day

Comment: This breaks when called from a different module, when called with a local variable as an argument, or when multiple globals have equal values.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.

Comment: i accepted the answer but someone granted -1 to sum to 0 again

Comment: Thanks for upvoting but that's different thing from [accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: ah ok, did it now. by the way, when i pass the parmeter as list_[0] these solution dont work. How to do it?

Comment: `list_[0]` is just first element of your list. Function `f()` looks for variables that are equal to some value, if you supply `list_[0]` that is `1` and we've never created such variable.